# I am getting an error while connecting to an sql DB in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, azure, jupyter-notebook, azure-active-directory, azure-sql-database

Facing issue with below code on jupyter while connecting with SQL DB.

```
    con = pyodbc.connect('Driver={ODBC Driver 13 for SQL 
    Server};Server='+server+';Database='+database+';Uid='+username+'
    ;Pwd='+passwor 
    d+';Encrypt=yes;TrustServerCertificate=no;Connection 
    Timeout=30;Authentication=ActiveDirectoryPassword')

    Error Description Below:
    OperationalError: ('08001', '[08001] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL 
    Server]SSL Provider: [error:140A90F1:lib(20):func(169):reason(241)] (-1) 
    (SQLDriverConnect)')
```

Comment: What service do you use on Azure? Azure Jupyter Notebook https://notebooks.azure.com or Azure Databricks?

Comment: Hey Peter I am using jupyter notebook here on my AZURE ML WorkSpace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assumed that you are using [Microsoft Azure Notebooks](https://notebooks.azure.com/), I tried to reproduce your issue successfully, as below.

[image]

It was caused by the connection string you used.

On Azure portal, you will see three ODBC connection string, as the figure below.

[image]

Obviously, you are trying to use the second one which required the username and password of an Azure Active Directory account, as the figure said from the offical document [`Using Azure Active Directory with the ODBC Driver`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/using-azure-active-directory)

[image]

And according to the same document, the ODBC Driver version 13.1 seems to not support this authentication way, please change to use ODBC Driver version 17 with `{ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server}`.

[image]

And first, please check `msodbcsql17` which has been installed.

[image]

However, I tried to connect using `msodbcsql17`, it failed by login timeout error. Even I tried to upgrade `pyodbc` from `3.1.1` to `4.0.26` via `!pip install pyodbc --upgrade`

[image]

So please try and may get the successful connection, if you have to authenticate AAD for SQL Database connection. Or switch to the first connection way, to use SQL Database username and password to connect by `pyodbc==3.1.1`(upgrade to `4.0.26` that will cause another error) and `{ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server}`, it works for me.

[image]

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hey Peter Thanks a ton for your help.Even i am able to connect through SQL authentication but facing issue with AAD authentication.

Comment: @GauravGangwar Sorry for not solving it, I have tried my best. If you can use an Azure Linux VM, it can work fine after I test.

Comment: Hey Peter no problem you tried well to fix it so thanks a lot.