# Trying to query Azure SQL Database with Azure ML / Docker Image

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-machine-learning-service

I wanted to do a realtime deployment of my model on azure, so I plan to create an image which firsts queries an ID in azure SQL db to get the required features, then predicts using my model and returns the predictions. The error I get from PyODBC library is that drivers are not installed

I tried it on the azure ML jupyter notebook to establish the connection and found that no drivers are being installed in the environment itself. After some research i found that i should create a docker image and deploy it there,  but i still met with the same results

```
    driver= '{ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server}'
    cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER='+driver+';SERVER='+server+';PORT=1433;DATABASE='+database+';UID='+username+';PWD='+ password+';Encrypt=yes'+';TrustServerCertificate=no'+';Connection Timeout=30;')
```

> ('01000', "[01000] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib 'ODBC
>   Driver 13 for SQL Server' : file not found (0) (SQLDriverConnect)")

i want a result to the query instead i get this message

Comment: It doesn't look like you've correctly installed the ODBC components in your container.  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/installing-the-microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: I tried doing this documentation - i tried installing the driver in my ubunto 16.04 OS provided by AML but this still does not work

Answer (score 1):

and/or you could use pymssql==2.1.1, if you add the following docker steps, in the deployment configuration (using either Environments or ContainerImages - preferred is Environments):

```py
from azureml.core import Environment
from azureml.core.environment import CondaDependencies
conda_dep = CondaDependencies()
conda_dep.add_pip_package('pymssql==2.1.1')
myenv = Environment(name="mssqlenv")
myenv.python.conda_dependencies=conda_dep
myenv.docker.enabled = True
myenv.docker.base_dockerfile = 'FROM mcr.microsoft.com/azureml/base:latest\nRUN apt-get update && apt-get -y install freetds-dev freetds-bin vim gcc'
myenv.docker.base_image = None
```

Or, if you're  using the ContainerImage class, you could add these Docker Steps

```py
from azureml.core.image import Image, ContainerImage
image_config = ContainerImage.image_configuration(runtime= "python", execution_script="score.py", conda_file="myenv.yml", docker_file="Dockerfile.steps")
# Assuming this : 
# RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y install freetds-dev freetds-bin vim gcc
# is in a file called Dockerfile.steps, it should produce the same result.
```

See this answer for more details on how I've done it using an Estimator Step and a custom docker container. You could use this Dockerfile to locally create a Docker container for that Estimator step (no need to do that if you're just using an Estimator run outside of a pipeline) :

```
FROM continuumio/miniconda3:4.4.10
RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y install freetds-dev freetds-bin gcc
RUN pip install Cython
```

For more details see this posting :[using estimator in pipeline with custom docker images](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58306383/10435556). Hope that helps!

Comment: Hey @omartin2010 , i tried building a docker using pymssql, but it is not able to build the environment as it is not able to build all the dependent packages in it, in my case "Cython"
If yhou have a work around it, I'd really appreciate it

Comment: Was this in a estimator step of a pipeline or on a regular estimator? And did you pin pymssql==2.1.1?

Answer (score 0):

you can use AzureML built in solution dataset to connect to your SQL server. 
To do so, you can first create an azure_sql_database datastore. [reference here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azureml-core/azureml.core.datastore%28class%29?view=azure-ml-py#register-azure-sql-database-workspace--datastore-name--server-name--database-name--tenant-id--client-id--client-secret--resource-url-none--authority-url-none--endpoint-none--overwrite-false-)

Then create a dataset by passing the datastore you created and the query you want to run. 
[reference here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/service/how-to-create-register-datasets#using-the-sdk)

sample code

```
from azureml.core import Dataset, Datastore, Workspace

workspace = Workspace.from_config()

sql_datastore = Datastore.register_azure_sql_database(workspace = workspace,
                                                      datastore_name = 'sql_dstore', 
                                                      server_name = 'your SQL server name', 
                                                      database_name = 'your SQL database name', 
                                                      tenant_id = 'your directory ID/tenant ID of the service principal', 
                                                      client_id = 'the Client ID/Application ID of the service principal', 
                                                      client_secret = 'the secret of the service principal')

sql_dataset = Dataset.Tabular.from_sql_query((sql_datastore, 'SELECT * FROM my_table'))
```

You can also do it via UI at [ml.azure.com](http://ml.azure.com) where you can register an azure SQL datastore using your user name and password.

[image]

Comment: Hey @sihui, I guess I'm new to AML and Azure SQL,but i don't think this can be used to form a connection between the two, given the parameters don't match I think

Comment: @Pankaj Are you trying to form the connection using your userID and password instead of service principal? Azureml datastore SDK does not support it as of today, but you can do so via UI. I've updated my answer above. Let me know whether it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Per my experience, I think the comment as @DavidBrowne-Microsoft said is right.

There is a similar SO thread [I am getting an error while connecting to an sql DB in Jupyter Notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56866757/i-am-getting-an-error-while-connecting-to-an-sql-db-in-jupyter-notebook/56868526#56868526) answered by me, which I think it will help you to install the latest `msodbcsql` driver for Linux on Microsoft Azure Notebook or Docker.

Meanwhile, there is a detail about the connection string for Azure SQL Database which you need to carefully note, that you should use `{ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server}` instead of `{ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server}` if your Azure SQL Database had been created recently (ignore the connection string shown in Azure portal).